# Count Variable by Subgroup and Over Time

Tags: r, count, grouping

I am working with panel data.  Specifically, I am dealing with data that is structured for duration analysis.  I am looking at when a U.S. state adopts a policy.  I have around 500 different policies, 50 states, and the data spans 40 years.  In R, I would like to construct a new variable that is a count of the number of states that have adopted a policy in the previous years.

Here is an example of the dataset (in one policy area coded as “A”).  “State” is the name of the state.  “Policy” is the specific policy area.  “Adopt” is whether a state formally implemented a policy in a given “year.”  Observations coded as zero indicates it was not adopted and 1 indicates it was adopted that year.

```
State   Year    Policy  Adopt
1       1970    A       0
1       1971    A       0
1       1972    A       1
2       1970    A       0
2       1971    A       0
2       1972    A       0
2       1973    A       1
3       1970    A       0
3       1971    A       0
3       1972    A       0  
3       1973    A       0
3       1974    A       1
```

I would like the new dataset to look like this.

```
State   Year    Policy  Adopt   Adopters_Count
1       1970    A       0       0
1       1971    A       0       0
1       1972    A       1       0
2       1970    A       0       0
2       1971    A       0       0
2       1972    A       0       0
2       1973    A       1       1
3       1970    A       0       0
3       1971    A       0       0
3       1972    A       0       0
3       1973    A       0       1
3       1974    A       1       2
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or R code that could produce such a variable?  I appreciate any help

Here is the code to product the sample dataset:

```
df1 <- data.frame(State = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3), year=c(1970,1971,1972, 1970,1971,1972,1973,1970,1971,1972,1973,1974), Policy=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"), Adopt=c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while and I am not sure this is the most straightforward answer, but it worked!

```
df1= df1%>%  mutate(ID = group_indices_( df1, .dots=c("policy", "year")))
df12=aggregate(df1$adopt, by=list(ID= df1$ID), FUN=sum)
df1=merge(df1, df12, by=c("ID"))
df1$adopt2= df1$x
df12= df1%>% select(ID, adopt2, policy)
df12=unique(df12)
df12$adopt3 <- do.call(c, tapply(df12$adopt2, df12$policy, FUN=cumsum))
df12$adopt4= df12$adopt3- df12$adopt2
df13=merge(df1, df12, by=c("policy"))
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Based on comments and answer by @Dyllan I think we can use the following.

```
df %>%
  group_by(Policy, year) %>%
  summarise(adopt2 = sum(Adopt)) %>%
  group_by(Policy) %>%
  mutate(adopt3 = cumsum(adopt2) - adopt2) %>%
  inner_join(df, by = "Policy") 

# A tibble: 60 x 7
# Groups:   Policy [1]
#   Policy year.x adopt2 adopt3 State year.y Adopt
#   <fct>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A        1970      0      0     1   1970     0
# 2 A        1970      0      0     1   1971     0
# 3 A        1970      0      0     1   1972     1
# 4 A        1970      0      0     2   1970     0
# 5 A        1970      0      0     2   1971     0
# 6 A        1970      0      0     2   1972     0
# 7 A        1970      0      0     2   1973     1
# 8 A        1970      0      0     3   1970     0
# 9 A        1970      0      0     3   1971     0
#10 A        1970      0      0     3   1972     0
# … with 50 more rows
```

---

**Original Answer**

We can `arrange` by `year` and `Policy` and create a count of cumulative adoption in each year and subtract it by 1 since we want to know how many policies were adopted before the current year. We use `pmax` here since we don't want count to be -1 for the years when the policy was not adopted. Also `group_by(Policy)` doesn't impact anything in the sample dataset provided since we have only one `Policy` but would be required in the actual dataset.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  arrange(year, Policy) %>%
  group_by(Policy) %>%
  mutate(Adopters_Count = pmax(cumsum(Adopt) - 1, 0)) %>%
  arrange(State)

#  State  year Policy Adopt Adopters_Count
#   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1     1  1970 A          0              0
# 2     1  1971 A          0              0
# 3     1  1972 A          1              0
# 4     2  1970 A          0              0
# 5     2  1971 A          0              0
# 6     2  1972 A          0              0
# 7     2  1973 A          1              1
# 8     3  1970 A          0              0
# 9     3  1971 A          0              0
#10     3  1972 A          0              0
#11     3  1973 A          0              1
#12     3  1974 A          1              2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It doesn't exactly create the variable that I would like.  Another way to explain the data I am trying to create, I am trying count the # of adoptions based on 2 different subgroups.  One group is a policy area.  The second group is year, but I would like to count the # of adoptions from all previous years (within a policy group).  If I am looking at Policy Area A in 2007, is there a way I can sum all the adoptions in Policy area A that took place before 2007 (i.e., all adoptions in 1960-2006)?  Is there a way to use aggregate? Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Dyllan I have updated the answer. See if it is helpful and gives you the correct answer.